# Solve the limits by alternative method

Tags: limits

We know, that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$ $(1+2+3+...+n)\over n^2$

= $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$  $1\over n^{2}$.${n(n+1)\over 2}$

= $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$ $1\over 2$$({1}+{1\over n})$=${1\over 2}$$({1}+{1\over ∞})$=$1\over 2$

But, doing it in alternate way by the property of algebra of limits:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}$ $(f±g)(x)$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}$ $f(x)$ $±$ $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}$ $g(x)$

The equation goes:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$ $(1+2+3+...+n)\over n^2$

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$1\over n^2$ + $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$2\over n^2$ + $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$3\over n^2$ +....+$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$n\over n^2$

=$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$1\over n^2$ + $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$2\over n^2$ + $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$3\over n^2$ +....+$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to ∞}$$n\over n^2$

= $0+0+0+...+0 = 0$ not $1\over 2$  [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to ∞}$ $c\over x^N$ = $0$]

Why does it contradict on solving alternately? If it is incorrect to solve it by the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The separation of limits work only for the finite sum. In other words if $\{a^i_n\}$ are convergent sequences for $i=1,..,k$ such that $k$ is finite, then you can have the following:
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^1_n+\dots+a^k_n)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a^1_n+\dots+\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a^k_n
$$
In your case, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{n^2}+\dots+\frac{n}{n^2})$ is indeed sum of infinite number of sequences and you cannot separate them.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! These precautions will definitely improve my grade!

Comment: What do you mean by an ending element and about which series are you talking?

Comment: @user99499, the finite sum means having $k$ different elements in the sum where $k$ remains fixed independent of $n$. No need to use terms like pattern, start and end.

Comment: @Arash, I got it! would it work for: lim x->inf (1+2+3+4)/n^2? or any other finite sum....